# Removing one value from ts() object in R without changing the class of the object

Tags: r, time-series

I have a dataset, which has `ts()` class.

The `dput` looks like this:

```
structure(c(0.0499999999999998, -0.0499999999999998, 0.12, 0.28, 
0.109999999999999, 0.0500000000000007, -0.44, 0.16, -0.11, -0.8, 
-0.24, 0.0800000000000001, -0.13, -0.19, 0.0500000000000007, 
0.56, -0.2, -0.0299999999999994, -0.130000000000001, -0.109999999999999, 
-0.0700000000000003, 0.0499999999999998, 0.100000000000001, -0.04, 
-0.0200000000000005, 0.13, -0.21, -0.149999999999999, -0.180000000000001, 
-0.13, -0.0800000000000001, -0.13, 0.0800000000000001, 0.41, 
0.0499999999999998, 0.19, -0.11, 0, -0.2, -0.13, 0.0300000000000002, 
-0.27, -0.159999999999999, -0.04, -0.0800000000000001, -0.0300000000000002, 
-0.04, -0.0299999999999998, 0.0600000000000001, -0.04, -0.11, 
-0.13, -0.12, 0.0500000000000003, -0.1, -0.12, -0.0299999999999998, 
-0.0100000000000002, 0.0700000000000003, 0.12, 0.0300000000000002, 
-0.11, 0.0899999999999999, 0.53, 0.3, 0.0899999999999999, 0.0300000000000002, 
-0.3, 0.0699999999999994, 0.2, -0.0300000000000002, -0.13, 0.04, 
0, -0.149999999999999, -0.0300000000000002, -0.0300000000000002, 
-0.00999999999999979, 0.04, -0.12, -0.04, -0.14, -0.19, 0.04, 
0.0600000000000001, -0.1, 0.17, 0.14, 0.0699999999999998, -0.14, 
-0.02, -0.0900000000000003, 0.14, 0.02, -0.0899999999999999, 
-0.21, 0.0299999999999998, -0.0899999999999999, 0, -0.0300000000000002, 
-0.13, 0, 0.02, 0.0100000000000002, 0.3, 0.43, -0.0499999999999998, 
0.0199999999999996, 0.0300000000000002, -0.16, -0.0300000000000002, 
-0.11, 0.0700000000000003, -0.0900000000000003, -0.0800000000000001, 
0.1, 0.02, 0.0300000000000002, 0.0800000000000001, 0.3, 0.11, 
0.0299999999999994, 0.12, -0.0199999999999996, -0.04, 0.0199999999999996, 
0.0800000000000001, 0.2, 0.04, -0.23, -0.18, -0.0899999999999999, 
-0.11, -0.12, -0.0699999999999994, -0.27, -0.0299999999999998, 
-0.15, -0.02, 0.0899999999999999, 0.0100000000000002, 0.02, -0.1, 
-0.15, -0.02, -0.14, -0.0800000000000001, -0.0699999999999998, 
-0.14, -0.0800000000000001), .Tsp = c(2008.16666666667, 2020.58333333333, 
12), class = "ts")
```

Visually it looks like:

[image]

I am trying to remove one value for March 2008. But it I use something

```
foo[-c(1:1)]
```

it converts data into `numeric` and it will not work for me.

How to remove this variable and keep the `ts()` class and date values? Thanks!

Comment: You can convert it to `NA` or convert it to `ts` with new `start`, `end` i.e. `foo[1] <- NA`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any of these should give the requested result.

The first uses `window.ts` to start at the indicated year and month.

The second also uses `window.ts` but specifies it in terms of the second time value rather than hard coding it.

The third replaces the first value with NA and then runs `na.omit` to remove it.  It should work if the series has no NA values.

The fourth adds the series to a zero series which is lagged forward and should work if the series has no NA values.

The fifth converts to zoo class where subscripting works and then converts back.

The sixth is the same as the second except it uses a different expression for the second time point.

```
window(foo, start = c(2008, 4))

window(foo, start = time(foo)[2])

na.omit(replace(foo, 1, NA))

foo + lag(0 * foo, -1)

library(zoo)
as.ts(as.zoo(foo)[-1])

window(foo, start = tsp(foo)[1] + deltat(foo))
```

Answer (score 0):

An option is to reconvert back to `ts`

```
foo2 <- ts(foo[-1], start = index(foo)[2], frequency = frequency(foo))
```

-output

```
foo2
#       Jan   Feb   Mar   Apr   May   Jun   Jul   Aug   Sep   Oct   Nov   Dec
#2008                   -0.05  0.12  0.28  0.11  0.05 -0.44  0.16 -0.11 -0.80
#2009 -0.24  0.08 -0.13 -0.19  0.05  0.56 -0.20 -0.03 -0.13 -0.11 -0.07  0.05
#2010  0.10 -0.04 -0.02  0.13 -0.21 -0.15 -0.18 -0.13 -0.08 -0.13  0.08  0.41
#2011  0.05  0.19 -0.11  0.00 -0.20 -0.13  0.03 -0.27 -0.16 -0.04 -0.08 -0.03
#2012 -0.04 -0.03  0.06 -0.04 -0.11 -0.13 -0.12  0.05 -0.10 -0.12 -0.03 -0.01
#2013  0.07  0.12  0.03 -0.11  0.09  0.53  0.30  0.09  0.03 -0.30  0.07  0.20
#2014 -0.03 -0.13  0.04  0.00 -0.15 -0.03 -0.03 -0.01  0.04 -0.12 -0.04 -0.14
#2015 -0.19  0.04  0.06 -0.10  0.17  0.14  0.07 -0.14 -0.02 -0.09  0.14  0.02
#2016 -0.09 -0.21  0.03 -0.09  0.00 -0.03 -0.13  0.00  0.02  0.01  0.30  0.43
#2017 -0.05  0.02  0.03 -0.16 -0.03 -0.11  0.07 -0.09 -0.08  0.10  0.02  0.03
#2018  0.08  0.30  0.11  0.03  0.12 -0.02 -0.04  0.02  0.08  0.20  0.04 -0.23
#2019 -0.18 -0.09 -0.11 -0.12 -0.07 -0.27 -0.03 -0.15 -0.02  0.09  0.01  0.02
#2020 -0.10 -0.15 -0.02 -0.14 -0.08 -0.07 -0.14 -0.08
```

---

or we assign the value to `NA`

```
foo[1] <- NA
```

Comment: Thanks for your time! The first option does not work for some reason. When I use your code, it gives me an error `Error: x is not a tsibble.`

Comment: The second solution formally works, but I am not sure, if my model like this `NA` or `0`.

Comment: But the length of my variable remains the same with `NA`, hence, it is still a problem. Because I cannot `cbind` two variables with different `length`.

Comment: @AnakinSkywalker it is not giving any error for me